# How can I edit a custom field with Rule and VBO of a NOT published node?

Tags: rules, views

I'm currently stuck in the creation of a custom rule.
I've created a content type "Avviso" with a publishing date field (start & end) and a custom field_stato with this values:

- Not active
- Active
- Terminated
- Archived

Now I would like to change the value of field_stato and publish all nodes with date_start < now < date_end. For that I've created a view with a VBO field, a Rule (triggered by the cron) and a component (of type rule) that do the job.

The problem is that the rule can see only node already published and -of course- cannot switch the node itself to "Published" state. With already published nodes the rule works fine.

Is there any restriction or permission with rules and unpublish content=?

(see images)
[image: Rule]
[image: Component]

Comment: For the rule-component interaction, I've followed this guide: https://www.drupal.org/node/1386746#comment-9738271

Comment: You probably need to look at the VBO view and make sure that it is not restricted by "Published"

Comment: No, my view has not any filter on published/unpublished state.. :-(

Comment: Hi, would you mind take a look at my issue here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/212173/if-field-date-is-15-days-away-from-today-change-another-field-value. I just need to change a field value but I can't figure out how... And as I can see you already did that. Would you mind explaining how? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Cron runs as an anonymous user. Ensure that the view permissions allow an anonymous user to access. Set the access to role:

[image: Permission dialog box for views]

Then, set the role to anonymous:

[image]

That should allow you to bypass the regular permissions that would normally not allow you to see it.

Also, ensure that your rule includes a rule to save the entity. I'm not 100% sure that it will save the entities you reference automatically, but it is more clear.

Also also, you may need to check the permissions on your rules to ensure that they can be executed by anonymous as well:

[image: rules access bypass]