# If field date is 15 days away from today, change another field value

Tags: entities, rules

OK, this is specific:

I have a content type with two fields:

1. First is a expiration date field (d-m-y format);
2. Second is a select list field: "green, red, yellow, empty"

WHAT I NEED:

When there is 15 days left for the expiration date of a specific node, the select list field from that node should automatically change to "yellow".

Is this possible using, for example, rules module? Is there any other option?

Thank you!

Comment: You can use a cron to check everyday day that kind of thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm.. This sounds like it could be done with Rules and [VBO](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations).

1. Create a VBO view of nodes that match your date requirement using filter `date field > relative date`. You might also want to filter out nodes that have already been changed.
2. Create a rule:

   - Event: Cron or maybe the [Rules Once per Day](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_onceperday) module
   - Action: Load a list of entity IDs from a VBO view
   - Action: Loop list
   - Action: Change / Add field using `Set a data value` if it's a single value field or `Add item to list` if it's a multi-value field.

EDIT: As of November 2017, this feature whereby VBO supplies Rules has been a bit broken and requires [a patch](https://www.drupal.org/node/2862858) to work.

Comment: Hi, I tried to do that but I can't find the action "change field". First, I created a VBO...I added the Bulk Operation to change the select list field. When I see the view page I have the option to change to green,yellow, red etc and it is working great. I also added the filter to show only the nodes which date field is between today and 15 days ago and that is working.
Now in the rules: I added event "Cron maintenance tasks are performed", I added no condition, and then in the actions I added just like you said. But I can't find the action "change field"... what am I doing wrong? thank you

Comment: Hi, I added components and I figured it out. You pointed me to the right direction so I'll accept your answer. Thanks

Comment: I should have said "Set a data value" for the last part. Glad it helped!

Comment: Hey Niall, I think you should integrate your last comment in your answer ...

Comment: @Pierre, I really love your solutions about VBO/Rules. Thanks for providing all the possible ways to use these modules. +1 for your thoughts

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens Edited.